# Typescript change object value type to string literal

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to change object value type to string literal without type assertion?

e.g.:

```
const foo = {
    bar: 'foobar',
}; // => typeof foo is { bar: string }
```

is it possible to change this to `{ bar: 'foobar' }` type without type assertion?

Comment: Use `as const`  and type infering will be strict

Comment: @MaciejSikora Do you mean `const foo = { bar: 'foobar' as const}`? Is there a way to do this for all values at once? I"m converting few very big objects into typescript and looking for the fastest way to achieve this

Comment: No, `const foo = { bar: 'foobar' } as const;`